# Assigning service usage in multiple nic

Tags: unix, networking

I have 2 nic card plugin. Now they are generated two IP, named - eth0 and eth1.

Lets say eth0 is 192.168.1.2 and eth1 is 192.168.1.3.

If  want to use db transaction with port 1521 with eth1 and ssh at eth0, how do i achieved this?

I a not finding any concert example how to achieved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure your ssh server to listen on eth0 IP by setting

```
ListenAddress 192.168.1.2
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

And in case of db transactions, Listen your db management server on 192.168.1.3

Edit:

Similarly if you are running clients on your system, you can use iptables rules which will send outgoing packets to eth0 if destination port is 22 (SSH server port) and to eth1 if the destination port is 1521 (DB Server port in your case).

Comment: This is going to be oracle client and connect to db server. So from the client how do i make all the transaction to process through eth1.

Comment: In that case you can add some iptables rule which checks that if the destination port is the db server port, then output the packet to eth1